# Какой использовать плагин WP для каталога в данном случае?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

Привет, не могу найти нужный плагин, чтобы сделать нечто похожее на WP, поделитесь советом, опытом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вёрстка шаблонов темы. Пример такой темы https://wordpress.org/themes/metro-creativex/

Comment: Если честно, ничего общего не нашёл, меня интересует каталог

Comment: "Ничего общего" не нашел? Значит вопрос задан некорректно. Ваши картинки имеют абсолютную схожесть - плиточное расположение+миниатюры+анонсы/тексты. А если Вам нужен каталог, то так и надо спрашивать. Каталогов в репо как грязи. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=catalog Впрочем, это не отменяет того, что подобны вывод (плиткой) - это вёрстка.  А будет ли плагин иметь шаблоны с такой вёрсткой или не - это дело десятое.  Это всегда можно сверстать